# Save Fingerprint2 result in Variable

Tags: javascript, fingerprintjs2

I am using Fingerprint2.js (Modern & flexible browser fingerprinting library, a successor to the original fingerprintjs http://valve.github.io/fingerprintjs2/)

I get hash fingerprint when i console.log inside the function. but when i store that result in some variable, it gives 'undifined'

```
Fingerprint2.get(options, function (components) {
  var values = components.map(function (component) { return component.value });
  console.log('insideFun -> ' + x64hash128(values.join(''), 31));
  return x64hash128(values.join(''), 31);
});
```

By this, i see a hash code in my console... but if i store the return value to some `var` it do not work.

if i use asyn/await it still do console value but not store in `var`

```
var guid = function guid() {
    var fpid;
    var options = {}
    let fp = (async function() {
        const components = await Fingerprint2.getPromise(options);

        var values = components.map(function (component) { return component.value });

        let fpid = x64hash128(values.join(''), 31);
        return fpid;
     })();
  return fpid;
};

guid();
```

it give `fpid is undefined`.

is there any way to handle this?

Comment: `Fingerprint2.get` is an asynchronous function (that's why you need to provide a callback to it); Doing `return ...` inside that callback won't have any effect. You could use [`getPromise`](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs2#get-and-getpromise) instead, and use `async/await`

Comment: will you please give me example... i am totally new to JS ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Fingerprint2.get` is an asynchronous function (that's why you need to provide a callback to it); Doing `return ...` inside that callback won't have any effect.

You could use [`getPromise`](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs2#get-and-getpromise) instead, to return a Promise, and use async/await to make your code look like it's synchronous (even though it's not):

```js
// This function is asynchronous,
// it does not return a fp, but a Promise that will
// resolve to a fp
var guid = function guid() {
    const options = {};
    return Fingerprint2.getPromise(options)
           .then(components => {
             const values = components.map({ value } => value);
             return x64hash128(values.join(''), 31);
           });
};

// And then, there are 2 ways to use it:

// Method 1 - using `.then`
guid()
  .then(fpid => { // When it's done
    console.log(fpid); // Now you can use it
    document.cookie = `fpid=${encodeURIComponent(fpid)}`;
  });
  

// Method 2 - using `async/await`
(async function() {
  const fpid = await guid();
  console.log(fpid); // Now you can use it
  document.cookie = `fpid=${encodeURIComponent(fpid)}`;
})();

// But this will never work:
// const fpid = guid();
// console.log(fpid); // Promise<pending>
```

The problem when you do this:

```
const fpid = guid();
console.log(fpid);
```

... is that `console.log` is executed before the FingerPrint was retrieved. Because FP2 is asynchronous. So you need to wait for the result before being able to use it.

Comment: sir i used same function but when i console `.then(console.log)` it console value but if i assign that value to some variable... it give error of undefined..

Comment: how can i do something like `var fp2 = FINGERPRINT_VALUE_HERE`

Comment: You either need to put your `var fp2 = ...` inside a `.then`, or to use `async`/`await`. There is no way around it, it's asynchronous. If you cannot figure it out, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62757452/edit) to add the code that is giving you problems, it will be easier to help you

Comment: i edited my question... added complete function that i am working on...

Comment: what i am doing is...to call guid() function and which will return me Fingerprint ID and i will store it in cookies ...

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. If you don't know how promises work, maybe [this 100 seconds YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvYYCGs45L4) will help you understand

Comment: it is working fine... but i have a function to set cookies dynamically ,  `set(name, value, minutes, path = "/") {` ... can i pass `fpid` to this function?.

Comment: You can use `set(name, fpid, minutes...)` only in the places where I did `document.cookie = ...` in my examples (where the value is actually available)

Comment: everything worked fine... also, can you give me some article of link to make my knowledge strong in this area please...

Comment: It's hard to choose, there are plenty of resources. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) would probably be a most "academic" source, but if you're looking for a shorter read, it looks like [this one](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-promises/) is fine